# Проблема с запуском Python console в Pycharm community (django)

Tags: python, django, консоль, отладка, settings

## Python console

from products.models import ProductCategory

ошибка: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

`вот models.py`

from django.db import models

```
        class  ProductCategory(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

       class Product(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
       description = models.TextField()
       price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
       quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images')
       category = models.ForeignKey(to=ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`полный traceback`

Comment: Вы забыли traceback прикрепить. Ошибка на русском: Запрошенная настройка INSTALLED_APPS, но настройки не настроены. Вы должны либо определить переменную окружения DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, либо вызвать settings.configure() перед доступом к настройкам - вам уже описали что надо делать